# Form not submitting even no errors and OK response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck with returning.

I need that if response is "ok", my form would be submitted else document wouldn't reload.

I've tried like that:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('.check-connection').click(function(){
    u = {};
    u["host"] = $('[name="host"]').val();
    u["db_user"] = $('[name="db_user"]').val();
    u["db_pass"] = $('[name="db_pass"]').val();
    u["db_name"] = $('[name="db_name"]').val();
    $.post('check-connection.php',{secure:true,data:u}).done(function(r){
        if(r == "ok"){
            /*
                here problems even returns ok
                alert(r); - gives answer ok if trying to check..
            */
            return true;
        } else {
            alert(r);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

Any ideas? offers?

Comment: please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: You should really use the proper $.post syntax for handling return values - https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: @JayBlanchard ?? the code looks OK (other than the `return` statements); it's using the Deferred mechanism instead of the 3rd parameter callback.

Comment: @Pointy I would have handled it in the .done(), just a preference.

Comment: The `$.post()` operation is **asynchronous**.  You can't return values.

Comment: Seems I'll need to think how to do this in other way..

Comment: your else statement is always going to be triggered unless the data returned by the post is actually the text `ok`, are you trying to test against the response code, like `200 OK`, or is your php script actually putting out `ok`?

Comment: I sincerely hope you are not exposing your DB information on the client. HUGE security issue.

Comment: PHP checks and response only OK or Error. Nothing else. It's just checking if user can connect database with entered details.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you might want to remove the last `return false;` because it is returning before the ajax completes.

Let it return when the `.done()` handler is executed.

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: I've tried.. But it isn't helped to.. Alerts not working and even response not equal OK it's returns true..

Answer (score 0):

You can not return a boolean from within the ajax done function and expect it to be passed back to the click handler. The ajax is asynchronous and so the click handler will complete execution before the ajax response is received.

The logic should be: call the ajax on a button click (not form submit), then submit the form from within the ajax success handler, else don't do anything.